# New JCheckboxes not appearing below eachother

Tags: java, layout, actionlistener, jcheckbox

I am trying to make a basic program where whenever you press a button, a `JCheckbox` is generated and added below the other `JCheckbox` on a panel. I figured out how to generate the `JCheckbox` with a `ActionListener` but I can't figure out how to get each new check box to appear below the previous one. Everything else seems to be working but I can't get this location thing to work.

```
        box.setVisible(true);

        _p.add(box);

        int i = 0;
        int u = i++;

        box.setAlignmentX(0);
        box.setAlignmentY(u);
```

Here is a sample of my code. I've been stuck on this problem for a very long time and would greatly appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JCheckbox` lives in a container like a `JPanel` (that means that you add checkbox to a panel) . A `JPanel` have a layoutManager. Take a look about [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

You could use `BoxLayout` with Y_AXIS orientation or a `GridLayout` with 1 column and n rows.

Example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CheckBoxTest {

    private JPanel panel;
    private int counter=0;

    public CheckBoxTest(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JButton button = new JButton(" Add checkbox ");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                panel.add(new JCheckBox("CheckBox"+Integer.toString(counter++)));
                //now tell the view to show the new components added
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                //optional sizes the window again to show all the checkbox
                SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(panel).pack();
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
    }


    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Checkbox example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(Boolean.TRUE);
        CheckBoxTest test = new CheckBoxTest();
        frame.add(test.panel);

        //sizes components
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Or you could read the tutorial and download the examples from the tutorial, because the tutorial also has an explanation about what the code does, unlike these examples. Plus this question is about adding the checkboxes when you click a button, so this example doesn't really help.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. I'm going to go through it in great detail to get a better idea of where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You could use a vertical `BoxLayout` or a `GridBagLayout` or maybe a `GridLayout`.

Whatever layout you choose to use the basic code for adding components to a visible GUI is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The other statements in your code are not necessary:

```
//box.setVisible(true); // components are visible by default
```

The following methods do not set a grid position.

```
//box.setAlignmentX(0);
//box.setAlignmentY(u);
```